# Eloquent - Laravel 9 - orderBy Subquery returns more than 1 row, I want 2 rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query

```
    $users = User::query()
        ->whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED);
        })
        ->orderByDesc(
            Post::select('updated_at')
                ->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
                ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
                ->whereColumn('user_id', 'users.id')
                ->limit(1)
        )
        ->with('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
                ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
                ->take(2);
        })
        ->take(4)
        ->get();
```

I'm ordering users by relation column using  [subquery ordering](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#subquery-ordering), it works, but I want to get 2 relation elements (posts), and the `->limit(1)` doesn't allow me to get 2 posts, If I remove that or increase to ->limit(2) I get this error

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more
> than 1 row select * from `users` where exists (select * from `posts`
> where `users`.`id` = `posts`.`user_id` and `state` = published and
> `posts`.`deleted_at` is null) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null order
> by (select `updated_at` from `posts` where `state` = published and
> `user_id` = `users`.`id` and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null order by
> `updated_at` desc limit 2) desc limit 4

I want to get 2 posts for each user, not only one, how can I do that?

I want to avoid at all costs is to use a foreach and within that foreach make multiple queries "->with('posts')"

adition:

I found the problem, If I delete the `->take(2)` in `->with('posts',...` relation I get all posts for each user, so, the `->take(2)` that I am using in posts, is limiting all the posts of the users and not for each user

Comment: Do you want to get 2 posts per user for ordering or for your result? I would assume the with logic take 2 would ensure you only get 2 posts.

Comment: I want to get 2 posts per user, max 4 users with 2 posts. that users need to ordered by posts date and each user with 2 newer posts

Comment: and doesn't the take 2 solve that on the with call?

Comment: no, it only gets a single Post, I have tried it in different ways and if I don't send the users to another function where I make another query then it doesn't work

Comment: I found the problem, If I delete the ->take(2) in ->with('posts',.... relation I get all posts for each user, so, the '->take(2)' that I am using in posts, is limiting all the posts of the users and not for each user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, If I delete the `->take(2)` in `->with('posts',...` relation I get all posts for each user, so, the `->take(2)` that I am using in posts, is limiting all the posts of the users and not for each user

I tried to change that take(2) to limit(2) but I get the same problem

```
         ->with('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
                ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
                ->limit(2);
        });
```

finally, I installed [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) library and It works, read library docs :)

I installed via composer `composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"`

then, In my `User` and `Post` models, I have imported and use the class HasEagerLimit

```
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
```

final query

```
    return User::query()
        ->whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED);
        })
        ->orderByDesc(
            Post::select('updated_at')
                ->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
                ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
                ->whereColumn('user_id', 'users.id')
                ->limit(1)
        )->with('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', PostStateEnum::PUBLISHED)
                ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
                ->limit(2);
        })->take(4)
        ->get();
```

and It works :)